# Check if Line Segment is inside Polygon

Tags: geometry, line, polygon, voronoi, delaunay

What is the most efficient way to check, whether a line segment is (partly or totaly) outside of a polygon?

In the picture, the green line segements are allowed, whereas the red ones are forbidden.

[image: picture]

Background information: This is for creating a Delaunay mesh.

One possible solution might be, to check, whether the line segment intersects any edge of the polygon or the middle point is outside the polygon. But is it really the most efficient way?

Comment: I doubt that you need to check line segments. Perhaps they should be built during mesh creation.

Comment: Delaunay triangulation results is a convex mesh, while your picture shows a concave case. If your algorithm uses these red segments in a temporary fashion then perhaps you want to enlighten us a bit, just to get the need of this "outside" check.

Comment: Are both endpoints of the line segment vertices of the polygon?

Comment: Yes they actually are